# Best way to fit a huge balanced binary tree into a rectangle

Tags: fractals

Does anyone know if there is a known algorithm/fractal to draw a very large balanced binary tree nicely, with minimal empty space when you put in on a piece of paper? Obviously, simplicity is also important—it’s easy to draw a binary tree that covers all the empty space, if you let the vertices and edges go all over the place. The standard way of drawing a balanced binary tree (below) is simple and easy to understand but it becomes very cramped at the bottom for a large depth (because of exponential growth).

The binary tree I want is probably bigger than this, so it’ll be more cramped at the bottom.

[image: binary tree]

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/H-Fractal.html